# Why does this expression keep evaluating to 0

Tags: java, math

The following `value1` keeps evaluating to 0, even though player1Disks and player2Disks are all above zero and not equal to one another.

```
int value1 = Math.round(100 * ((player1Disks - player2Disks)/(player1Disks + player2Disks)));`
```

Here are some example inputs for `player1Disks` and `player2Disks` respectively:
`[5,8], [6,8], [8,4], etc.`

However, all these are evaluating to zero. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The integer division evaluates to `0` in the three cases you presented. `0*100` still equals `0`.

You should multiply by `100` first, and then divide. Or better yet, don't use `int`.

First one: `-3/13 = 0`

Second one: `-2/14 = 0`

Third one: `-4/12 = 0`

Comment: @PM77-1 None of those are `4/3`

Comment: How could I write this expression to get an integer value?

Comment: Assuming you don't really care about maintaining a high precision, just cast to `double` and perform double arithmetic.